# Renaming all files in the folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

How to rename all files in the folder using Windows batch?
Basically, the part of the name starting from `_Done` should be removed:

`some_file_name_Done_34534576456.CSV` -> `some_file_name.CSV`
`some_other_file_name_Done_23232343.CSV` -> `some_other_file_name.CSV`

Comment: You'd probably find [Bulk Rename Here](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) more intuitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use third-party apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, solution in Batch:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%i in (*.*) do call:process "%%~i"
GOTO :eof

:process
set "fname=%~n1"
set "tname=%fname:*_Done=%"
if "%fname%"=="%tname%" echo %~1: nothing to do&goto :eof
set "fname=!fname:_Done%tname%=!%~x1"
if exist "%fname%" echo %fname%: already exists&goto :eof
ren "%~1" "%fname%"
goto :eof

endlocal
```

Edit: changed some `!` to `%` for clarification. This doesn't change the effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using another language, you can rename with regular expressions.  Here's what you asked for in JScript.  Save this as something.js, put it in the directory containing your CSV files, and run it with `cscript /nologo something.js`.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder(".");

var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

while (!files.atEnd()) {
    var file = '' + files.item();
    if (/\.csv$/i.test(file)) {
        var dest = file.replace(/_Done[^\.]+/i, '');
        if (dest != file) {
            WSH.Echo('Renaming ' + file + ' -> ' + dest);
            files.item().Move(dest);
        }
    }
    files.moveNext();
}
```