# VBA Replace all Files in Folder with Today's Date in the middle

Tags: vba, ms-access, file-rename

I am looking to utilize a batch file or VBA to replace the date in all files in a folder with today's date.

I have searched here and on other forums and have found the below to be the closest to what I want to achieve but they are doing a unique DateStamp format: [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523995/renaming-all-files-in-the-folder)

Here is the code from that link

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder(".");

var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

while (!files.atEnd()) {
    var file = '' + files.item();
    if (/\.csv$/i.test(file)) {
        var dest = file.replace(/_Done[^\.]+/i, '');
        if (dest != file) {
            WSH.Echo('Renaming ' + file + ' -> ' + dest);
            files.item().Move(dest);
        }
    }
    files.moveNext();
}
```

Example 1:

```
PLOG - (Daymon) Raritan - 2018.07.16 - (WB) OTC
--needs to be --
PLOG - (Daymon) Raritan - 2019.07.17 - (WB) OTC
```

Example 2:

```
PLOG - (Flagship+) Ardo - 2019.06.03 - (FRO) Vegetables and Vegetable
--needs to be--
PLOG - (Flagship+) Ardo - 2019.07.17 - (FRO) Vegetables and Vegetable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the VBA solution involving `fso`  and `regex` will do the required. (Though failed to understand what is meant by recursive.) May add reference (VBA project Window - Tools - Reference) and add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression ..."

```
Sub test()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As Folder, fl As File
Dim Rg As RegExp
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\users\user\desktop\Folder1") ' Modify folder name to your choice

Set Rg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  With Rg
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "(([\d]{4}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}))"

      For Each fl In fld.Files
        If .test(fl.Name) Then
        fl.Name = .Replace(fl.Name, Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd"))
        Else
        Debug.Print fl.Name & " Not renamed"
        End If
     Next
  End With

End Sub
```